# Another grep / awk q, parsing diskpart output

Tags: powershell

I've googled this a lot and there are a lot of similar questions but I can't figure out how to put them together to make it work for me. Also, the fact that MS decided to leave dynamic volumes out of their PowerShell cmdlets is really frustrating.

In the following code I'm trying to identify that "Disk 2" is dynamic.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> echo 'list disk' | diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.14393.0

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: AHPAP2704

DISKPART> 
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online           65 GB      0 B         
  Disk 1    Online           20 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 2    Offline          50 GB      0 B   *
```

Ideally from the output above I'm going to set a variable to identify the dynamic volume (my script will always only have one) so when complete I'm left with something like `$DynDisk = 2`.

When I pipe the output to `Get-Member` the only member types containing property in the name are `Chars` and `Length`.

Is there an easy way to get the data into an array or a better method? Or, any chance there is some hidden `grep` and `awk` like cmdlets out there?

Comment: get-disk only returns disk 0 and 1
get-volume doesn't return anything about volumes on disk 2 since it's offline

Comment: I don't have a system with an offline disk, so I can't test, but have you tried working with WMI objects? Something like: `get-wmiobject Win32_DiskDrive|Where{'Dynamic' -in $_.Qualifiers}`

Comment: I got really excited for a moment because it does return all 3 disks. I don't see a way to determine which one has a dynamic volume on it though. The only reference to "dyn" is

    Qualifiers                  : {dynamic, Locale, provider, UUID}

which shows up on all 3 volumes if they are dynamic or not. That led me to try get-wmiobject win32_volume but it didn't display the offline dynamic volume.

Comment: Those Qualifiers are actually objects it looks like. Check out `(get-wmiobject Win32_DiskDrive).Qualifiers['Dynamic']` and you'll see that it's got a `Value` property that's True/False. So this should get you your Dynamic drives: `$DynDisk=get-wmiobject Win32_DiskDrive|Where{$_.Qualifiers['Dynamic'].Value}`

Comment: I'm not getting errors but the first command returns nothing. When I drop the `['dynamic']`it returns info but I think it's about the fields, not the data itself. The second command also returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diskpart` output isn't trimmed, so you can parse the relevant information from the end of the string, e.g. like this:

```
$re = 'disk (\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+ .?b)\s+(\d+ .?b)  (.*)'

'list disk' | diskpart | Select-String -Pattern $re | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    ID        = [int]$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    Status    = $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value -eq 'online'
    Size      = $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value
    FreeSpace = $_.Matches.Groups[4].Value
    Dynamic   = $_.Matches.Groups[5].Value.Substring(0, 3).Trim() -eq '*'
    GPT       = $_.Matches.Groups[5].Value.Substring(4, 3).Trim() -eq '*'
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume that's right up the alley of what I'm really looking for but I can't even troubleshoot why it's not working. Can you explain to a PS noob what it's doing?

Comment: it's telling me Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"
At line:4 char:3
+   New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: My mistake. The offset in the second `Substring()` must be 4, not 5. Fixed.

Comment: As for an explanation: The code snippet basically uses [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)  with a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) to match the disk info lines and parse information from them. The relevant bits and pieces are selected via [capturing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx) in the regular expression, whose values can be accessed via `$_.Matches.Groups[]` in the `ForEach-Object` loop.

Comment: Thank you. it does exactly what I was looking for. Time for me to dig into how that select-string cmdlet works. The help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was another half hour of googling. 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskPartexe-Powershell-0f7a1bab

That script creates 3 objects which have properties I know now to handle