# How to parse the .txt file and know that there is no letter assigned to the volume listed

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which has contents listed due to commands

```
select disk 0,
select partition 1,
detail partition
```

[image]

Is there a way I can script using PowerShell/Batch that can tell me there is no Letter (Ltr) assigned to volume 4. It should say that "no letter is assigned for this Volume 4".

Note: I have tried already the below way, but I think it's not good way of getting the result.

```
Get-Content .\test.txt
$test.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize
$x = $test[21][15]
if ($x -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "No letter assigned. Retrying to Generate a New  letter"
}
```

Comment: Do you want powershell or batch to do this?

Comment: I would prefer powershell to do this

Comment: gone now. Let me see If I can code it for him

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but the text itself - sanitized if necessary.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42680382/1630171).

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess around with a text file - just query the partitions directly in PowerShell.

```
$nodriveletter = Get-partition | where { (-not $_.driveletter) -and $_.type -ne "Reserved"} |select disknumber,partitionnumber

$nodriveletter

disknumber partitionnumber
---------- ---------------
         3               2
```

You can then do a `Foreach` on the results to process any unconfigured partition.

If you want to know what letters are already in use, get all the partition information and extract the results you want after.

```
$Partitions = Get-partition | where { $_.type -ne "Reserved"} 
$noDriveLetter = $partitions | where { -not $_.driveletter} | select disknumber,partitionnumber
$driveletters = $partitions.driveletter #grabs all driveletters in use
```

Comment: This answer is precise.

Comment: As i only want to query volume labels under Disk 0,partition 1 ,then how do i set the disknumber to 0 and paritionnumber to 1.

Comment: Above code is giving me results which includes C and D drive. Its like --> null,null,C,D, null .Basically i am using diskpart to mount a vhdx file hence i do select vhdx/disk 0 , select partition 1 and followed by detail partition.

Comment: I suggest you do `Get-Partition | fl` to look at the properties you can inspect in this cmdlet (it's really getting the data out of WMI). In this instance, you could make the Where clause `{ $_.type -ne "Reserved" -and $_.disknumber -eq 0}`. Since I don't know your hardware, you will have to experiment.

Comment: Tried above script with local drives and works perfectly fine. However as i am working with vhdx file to mount the virtual disk, how do i select that virtual disk using PS ? I mean first i want to select the vdisk (not attach) then execute above logic